# Bonobo Git Server Team Description

Tags: active-directory, bonobo

I've set up a 6.3.0 **Bonobo Git Server** with **Active Directory Membership Service**.

On the web-frontend at the **Teams** page, only the team name is shown, the description is empty.

Where do I have to describe the `Teams`? Does it get this information from the Active Directory fields?

Answer (score 0):

In this case Bonobo gets team description from Active Directory Group description field.